# How to dynamically create Folder in batch file - CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have my source folder that contains many, many folders that are named like this:

[image]

What I am trying to do is essentially create new, empty folders with those exact names.

This could be done is 2 ways I think:

1. The dates are exactly 7 days apart, so the code could create the folders dynamically, given a start date.

or

2. Loop through the source folder, and create a new empty folder with that name, in my target folder.

I have never written a batch file. I was able to get this far, listing the directories though:

```
@echo

setlocal

FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO echo We found %%~nxG

endlocal
```

Does anyone know how to take the name found in the FOR statement, and create a folder in a specific directory?

Thanks! The syntax here sure is different!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest an easier method involving [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy):

```bat
RoboCopy "SourceDir" "TargetDir" /E /Lev:2 /Create /XF *>NUL
```

Obviously you'd replace `SourceDir` with the directory location holding your date named directories, and `TargetDir` would be the directory location where you're wanting to replicate those names.

*You can use just `.` for the current directory if it is the source or target.*

---

For information purposes, to do it using the method in your question, you'd simply need to use the `M`ake `D`irectory command, `MkDir`|`MD`:

```bat
For /D %%A In ("SourceDir\*")Do MD "TargetDir\%%~nxA"
```

*If the current directory is either `SourceDir` or `TargetDir`, you can remove it and it's trailing backslash.*

Comment: AWESOME!! Worked great, I had no idea of this RoboCopy!

Answer (score 1):

Another way, if you wanted to use PowerShell. Works exactly the same on Mac and Linux.

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path './srcdir' | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination './destdir' }
```